# Why was the Titles of Nobility Amendment proposed?

Tags: united-states, constitution, nobility

Why is it that the Titles of Nobility Amendment was proposed in congress? Were there instances of Americans accepting foreign noble titles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Titles of Nobility Amendment was prompted by the marriage of Jérôme-Napoléon Bonaparte, brother of Napolean Bonaparte, and Elizabeth Patterson Bonaparte who together had a child named Jérôme Napoléon Bonaparte. She hoped to bring this boy up within the French aristocracy. However, it is debated whether congress proposed the amendment to restrict the child's citizenship or Elizabeth's. While the marriage was annulled in 1805, 5 years before the amendment's proposal. These are the two theories because she was stylized as Duchess of Baltimore in discussions about the amendment and at least one representative is thought to have related this to whether members of the French nobility would hold American citizenship.